# vim editor: How to toggle split windows in different direction

Tags: linux, vim, split

In vim, I am using `Ctrl-w` `w` to toggle between split windows. However, this toggling goes in one direction only. i.e., usually left to right in a cyclic manner.

When there are a large number of split windows, it takes a lot of effort to switch to the window immediately to the left. Are there any shortcuts to switch windows in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I assume you mean you are repeating the command, eg `ctrl-w ctrl-w`.)

Use the standard `h`, `j`, `k`, and `l` movement keys, eg:

- `ctrl-w h` - select pane to the left
- `ctrl-w j` - select pane below
- `ctrl-w k` - select pane above
- `ctrl-w l` - select pane to the right

Comment: Not clear for me :( I tried pressing ctrl-w-h to move to left pane, but did not work

Comment: @SathishKrishnan let go of the control key (and w) after typing `<c-w>`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ctrl+W` followed by one of `hjkl` to move to the desired direction.

I've put a map into my `.vimrc` that goes like this:

```
map <C-J> <C-W>j
```

to ommit the `Ctrl+W` stroke.

Comment: I use the same approach. The only issue I had to deal with was that I was used to press `<C-l>` to redraw the window. Solution is easy: `noremap <C-L> <C-W>l<C-L>` moves me to the left window _and_ redraws the windows.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hit `<C-w>` twice, keeping the Ctrl key pressed and hitting `w` twice works just as well. You don't even need to keep the Ctrl key pressed, actually: `<C-w>w` is the exact equivalent of `<C-w><C-w>`: hit `<C-w>` then hit `w`.

That said, the opposite of `<C-w>w` is simply `<C-w>W` (uppercase W, same logic as `:bn/:bN` or `gt/gT`).

See `:help window-move-cursor`.

Comment: I actually meant `<C-w> w` only. The uppercase logic did help me!

Comment: Well, `<C-w>W` is exactly what you asked for.